# MySQL Index differences

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, explain

I have a query that is having different performances in two different instances of mysql server, both with apparently the same tables and indexes. Here is the query:

```
select t.id, t.artist, t.title, count(*) from `raw_detection` r, tracks t where t.id = r.`track_id`
and r.duplicated = false
and (t.title = '' or t.title is null or t.artist = '' or t.artist is null)
group by 1,2,3
order by count(*) desc;
```

When I do an `explain` with this query, the fast server responds:

```
id  s_type  table   type  possible_keys    key  key_len ref rows Extra   
1   SIMPLE  t   index_merge PRIMARY,index_tracks_on_title,index_tracks_on_artist    index_tracks_on_title,index_tracks_on_artist    602,602 NULL    11812   Using sort_union(index_tracks_on_title,index_tracks_on_artist); Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  r   ref index_raw_detection_on_duplicated_and_created_at,index_raw_detection_on_track_id    index_raw_detection_on_track_id 4   playax.t.id 84  Using where
```

And the slow server is different:

```
id  s_type  table   type  possible_keys    key  key_len ref rows Extra   
1   SIMPLE  t   ALL PRIMARY,index_tracks_on_title,index_tracks_on_artist    NULL    NULL    NULL    177313  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  r   ref index_raw_detection_on_duplicated_and_created_at,index_raw_detection_on_track_id    index_raw_detection_on_track_id 4   playax.t.id 20  Using where
```

Why this is happending?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `(t.title = '' or t.title is null or t.artist = '' or t.artist is null)`?

Comment: Try updating statistics with [ANALYZE TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/analyze-table.html) on both tables and rerunning your queries. Available resources go into determining which query plan mysql uses so if your servers have different hardware (or load) that may be part of it